# Know-it-alls--a synonym

Tags: synonyms

Both my husband and my sister are know-it-alls who try to do everything without knowledge or ability to do so.  My husband wants to remove my dogs sutures to save money.  My sister's motivations are often the same--to save money.  What is this person called?

Comment: The question lacks evidence of research.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a *do-it-yourselfer*.

Comment: Since the motivation is money, I would call them **frugal**. Also, **penny-wise-dollar-dumb** comes to mind because it sounds like they are frugal to a fault.

Comment: Two daughters related by marriage are daughters-in-law. Why wouldn't your two wanna-be surgeons be knows-it-all? : )

Comment: They could also be called *thrifty* or *frugal*, which would emphasize that neither likes to "waste" money. But those terms are not synonyms for *know-it-all*

Comment: related to the description in the body: **1** [How can I explain the difference between “thrifty” and “stingy”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/119983/how-can-i-explain-the-difference-between-thrifty-and-stingy) **2.** [What is a word for a person who uses resources to the maximum?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265962/what-is-a-word-for-a-person-who-uses-resources-to-the-maximum) **3** [Is there a single word for “money-mindedness”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19216/is-there-a-single-word-for-money-mindedness)

Comment: A very common synonym is "SE user with lots of karma"

Answer (score 2):

I have some singularly unflattering suggestions for you.

For the medically pretentious overtones: [Quack](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quack)

> a person who pretends, professionally or publicly, to skill, knowledge, or qualifications he or she does not possess; a charlatan.

More of the fraudster type: [Charlatan](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/charlatan)

> A person falsely claiming to have a special knowledge or skill:
>   *a self-confessed con artist and charlatan*

Perhaps the most neutral of the bunch: [Pretender](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pretender)

> a person who makes unjustified or false claims, statements, etc., as about personal status, abilities, intentions, or the like:
>   *a pretender to literary genius.*

References:
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quack
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/charlatan
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/pretender